# Possible to display:none this without JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

I have a link that gets embedded dynamically by a script I run on a site. Let's say for arguments sake that the link looks like:

```
<a href="http://foo/bar.php" target="_blank">some stuff</a>
```

Is it possible to set a CSS Selector that will set display:none on all links containing http://foo/? Am I going to have to write a JavaScript event handler that checks for the injection into the DOM and then hide it through that?

What's the best way to handle this? If it's with JavaScript, can I see an example in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Yes; there's a "starts-with" selector, as defined **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#attribute-substrings)**. You would use: `a[href^="http://foo/"]`. Note that this isn't necessarily supported in all browsers.

Comment: Note that this will not work in all browsers (IE6 for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a css selector to do this, but browser support may be limited.

```
a[href=http://foo/]
```

You can use the same selector with jQuery and it should work everywhere jQuery does.

```
$("a[href=http://foo/]")
```

More info on jQuery selectors can by found here: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: That won't quite work, because it'd match `a` tags whose `href` attribute is exactly `http://foo/`, which isn't what he wanted.